# Populate data by only using the id from another collection

Tags: reactjs, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, reference

I am building a table in React front end , I have and array list filled with id's.I want to populate the table by only using the Id's.

The Ids are filled in my customer collection

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private  List<LinkedUsersID>linkedUsersId;


public class User{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private  List<LinkedUsersID>linkedUsersId;
```

Someone metioned to me that I can reffrence the ids to a mongo  collection and the data will populate itself in the table. Use Id to refer to the user collection and get data with that specific id and populate the Table

Can someone please explain or share a link on how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$lookup` in aggregation like this

```
{
    $lookup:{
       from:"user" ,// user collection
       localField:"linkedUsersId",
       foreignField:"id",
       as:"newUserField"
    }
}
```

now run this aggregate on customer collection and returns user data in `newUserField`

Comment: Hi thank for the reply but I am new to this, where do I add this to use it in the frontend.  Do i add it with the controller that get all the data and the call the api normally in the frontend . @mohammad Naimi